# Allow access to bucket by all applications in a Google project or VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a single Google Cloud Platform project. I would like put data into a GCS bucket and allow any application or resource in this project to read this data but not let the public have any access to this data. Can this be done without having to grant specific access each time I add a new resource to the project?

Answer (score 0):

This is already the case when creating Buckets. By default, the public won’t have access to the bucket data. There are [steps](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) you must take to make the resource publicly available.

The bucket objects will only be available within the project it is in, and to any account you grant it [permission](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions) to.